# Replace regions in a raster image with values from another image in python

Tags: python, numpy, open-source, gdal

I have two raster images of the same area and x,y dimensions as numpy arrays. Image 1 is a land-use classification (e.g. with classes 0 to 5) and image 2 is a cloud-shadow mask (with the values: 0 = cloudfree, 255 = cloud/ shadow areas). 
 
I want to combine those images. Either take/clip all the 255 values from image 2 and mosaic them onto image 1. OR replace all the 0 values in image 2 with the values found at the specific pixel position in image 1.

I tried to make the 2d arrays 1d and replace the 0 values but then couldn't convert it correctly back into 2d.

What would be the easiest or best way to do this raster calculation completely open-source in python???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with numpy's boolean indexing feature.

```
img1 = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 1, 0]])
img2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8]])
bool_arr = img1 == 0
img1[bool_arr] = img2[bool_arr]
print(img1)
# outputs: [[1 1 3 1]
#           [1 6 1 8]]
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot. 
What if my img2 has floating values. You also have an idea how to integrate that?

Comment: @ChristinAbel You can use `<, >, <=, >=` to create boolean arrays with float values, e.g. replace `img1 == 0` with `img1 < 2` above.  Numpy also has a number of other element-wise logical functions which you can read about here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html

Comment: I just realised what I have now is a whole different problem .. because I have my img1 - 2 integer values, 2d (x, y) but my img2 has changed: floating values, 3d (ndim, x, y). Every array dimension represents a band in my raster layer. ...since img1 is the cloud/ shadow mask, it must be added to every dimension/ band of img2. So I want to loop through the ndim, modify every (x, y) array and save it as 3d array in the end again...